# HighCharts column to pie

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, highcharts

I have the following chart in column format which works well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    get_data();

    function get_data() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_data.aspx',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(results) { 

                var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart( {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'chart',
                        defaultSeriesType: 'column'
                    },
                    series: results
                });

            }
        });
    }
});
```

But when I try changing the `defaultSeriesType` to `pie`, I just get a single value in the pie.  I am assuming I need to format my json data differently for pie charts?

The chart above is using the following json data:

```
[
    {
        "name": "DEP1",
        "data": [
            100
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "DEP2",
        "data": [
            200
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "DEP3",
        "data": [
            300
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "DEP4",
        "data": [
            400
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "DEP5",
        "data": [
            500
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "DEP6",
        "data": [
            600
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic, your data needs to be in the format

```
[
  ["DEP1", 100],
  ["DEP2", 200],
  ...,
  ["DEP6", 600]
]
```

Comment: Yes the example shows 2d array but there is no reason you cannot use an object array: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data